# Powershell foreach $line issue

Tags: powershell, foreach

```
$outfilepath = "C:\scripts\hostlist.csv"
Get-Printer | select portname | Export-Csv "$outfilepath" -NoTypeInformation -NoClobber
$hostlist = get-content -path "$outfilepath"
$hostlist = $hostlist -Replace '"'

foreach ($line in $hostlist){
$o=Resolve-DnsName -Name $LINE 
$results+=$o
}
$results | Export-CSV -Path "C:\scripts\printerips.csv" -NoTypeInformation -NoClobber
```

Hello, I am trying to grab a list of all printers in our print server and output the IP address. Basically translate any printers responding to DNS to IP, or if there is a better way to list the IP for even those not setup as hostname that would also work. For some reason I had this working but when moved to another server I am not able to execute. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "not able to execute" - what is the error message you're seeing? please update your question.

Comment: Why output the results of `Get-Printer` to CSV first, then open it as 'normal' textfile, ruin it by removing all the quotes and ignoring the fact that the first line will be the header 'PortName' where you can do `$results = (Get-Printer).PortName | ForEach-Object { Resolve-DnsName -Name $_ -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue }` or similar instead?

Comment: Perfect! sorry I am still learning.

Comment: Theo's comment offers the best solution. As for what your immediate problem may be: `$result` is never initialized as an array `$result = @()`, which is required for adding elements with `+=` later. Also note that this method of building an array is inefficient, because a new array has to be created every time `+=` is used. A simpler and much more efficient approach is to use the `foreach` statement _as an expression_, which makes PowerShell collect the output in an array for you: `$results  = foreach ($line in $hostlist) { Resolve-DnsName -Name $LINE }`